# Console.warn failed to resolve component [Vue, Quasar] in tests Jest

Tags: javascript, vue.js, unit-testing, jestjs, quasar-framework

My component is written in Vue 3 and Quasar and I test it with Jest. This is an exemple of a test:

```
import { factory_mount } from '@/test-utils';
import VueBtn from '@/components/VueBtn.vue';
import { btnDesc } from '@/service/btnDesc';
import { installQuasarPlugin } from "@quasar/quasar-app-extention-testing-unit-test";

installQuasarPlugin();

const typesBtn = Object.keys(btnDesc);

describe("Button", () => {
    typesBtn.forEach((type) => {
        describe(`Testing button type: ${type}`, () => {
            let wrapper;

            beforeEach(() => {
                const componentResult = factory_mount(VueBtn, { type });
                wrapper = componentResult.wrapper;
            });

            it("btn exists", () => {
                expect(wrapper.exists()).toBe(true);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

This test runs well but when I run it I have a console.warn: failed to resolve component: q-btn if this is a native custom element make sure to include it from component resolution via compilerOptions.isCustomElement. At the moment I run hundreds of tests like this and I have warnings for almost each of them and parasite test results. How to fix this console warning?

Comment: It's unknown what factory_mount is. That Quasar comps are registered with installQuasarPlugin is undocumented behaviour. https://github.com/quasarframework/quasar-testing/blob/dev/packages/unit-jest/src/helpers/install-quasar-plugin.ts#L6-L8 . Try to explicitly add QBtn